# Create MVC application using AD authentication (Not ADFS)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory

I am creating a new MVC intranet application in Visual Studio 2017.

I would like to use active directory to authenticate (and authorise) various controllers, but not Active Directory Federation Sever (as we don't use it).

Here are the steps I've taken:

1. New Project -> ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)
2. Select MVC
3. Click Change Authentication
4. Select 'Work or School Accounts'
5. Select 'On-Premises'

Now the On-Premises Authority requires a metadata document URL. I understand that this is the external url for a ADFS... which we do not have.

How can I set up my application so that it uses our AD? I also need to make use of groups in AD (eg Allow users in **WebAdmin** group to access the **Admin** controller etc).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was using the wrong setting.  If you want to use standard AD, choose Windows Authentication.

"Work or School Accounts" only seems to be for ADFS.

Once your application is initialized, go to the web.config.

You will see something like this

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

We need to add the AD groups functionality to our web.config. After this is done your system.web section should look like this:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>

    <!--NEW-->
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>


    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
```

You will now be able to decorate your controller classes / action methods with the following:

[Authorize(Roles = @"YourDomain\Some AD Group Name")]

or the usual code:

User.IsInRole(@"YourDomain\Some AD Group Name"))